# Python: Merge specific cols in similar csv files on 'Date' and save on disk

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I'm totally new to Python and is trying to write code for this problem:

A) There are multiple *.csv files inside a directory , all of which have the same column headers and structure. Example file names:
Google.csv, Alphabet.csv, Teva.csv, Bosch.csv

Example content inside file named Google.csv:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close
2000-01-06,15,32,33.7,49.2
2000-01-07,33.1,10.1,57.3,62
2000-01-10,221,62.4,66.9,790.5
2000-01-11,3.3,1.78,43.2,52.1
2000-01-12,73.2,54.0,121.6,89.4
```

Example content inside file named Teva.csv:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close
2000-01-01,115,312,332.7,449.2
2000-01-02,33.1,10.1,59.3,662
2000-01-03,22.1,623.4,663.9,794.5
2000-01-06,34.3,13.78,43.2,52.1
2000-01-07,703.2,504.0,121.6,879.4
```

B) There is a file 'List.csv' which consists of some company names, which is a subset of the csv files mentioned in the above directory. Example content:

```
Company
Google
Teva
```

C) There is another file 'Dates.txt' which consists only of some dates. Example content:

```
Date,
2000-01-01,
2000-01-02,
2000-01-03,
2000-01-06,
2000-01-07,
2000-01-08,
2000-01-09,
```

My aim is to merge only those *.csv files (A) listed in List.txt (B), with 'Date' in Dates.txt (C) as key, choose only the column with header 'Low' and save on disk as a csv file.

The final csv file saved on disk is supposed to look like this:

```
Date,Google,Teva
2000-01-01,,332.7
2000-01-02,,59.3
2000-01-03,,663.9
2000-01-06,33.7,43.2
2000-01-07,57.3,121.6
```

**This is the code I managed to piece together:**

```
import os; import numpy as np; import csv; import pandas as pd; from shutil import copyfile
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500); pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500); pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
os.chdir('D:/SO/'); #print (os.getcwd())

open('temp.txt', 'a').close()
dst = 'Dates.txt';   temp1 = 'temp.txt'
path = "D:/SO/dir/";   directory = os.fsencode(path)

with open('temp.txt', 'w', newline='') as temp_date:
    copyfile(dst, temp1)
    f1 = pd.read_csv('Dates.txt', index_col = 1);  df1 = pd.DataFrame(f1);  # Read the dates in Dates.txt for joining
    with open('List.csv','r') as mylist:
        data = csv.reader(mylist, delimiter = ",")
        #next(data, None) # discard the header
        for i in data:
            c =i[0] + '.csv';  #print (c)#Add .csv to each line (CompanyName) in List.txt for searching the directory
            for file in os.listdir(path):       # Search for the file in directory
                if c in file:                 # if found,
                    print (file)
                    f2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file));     df2 = pd.DataFrame(f2);  #print(df2.head(5))
                    f3= f1.merge(f2, how='left',on=['Date']); df3 = pd.DataFrame(f3); 
                    df3 = df3.drop(df3.columns[[1,2,4]], axis=1);  print(df3.head(10), '\n')  # merge
            continue
```

Output so far:

```
Google.csv
         Date   Low
0  2000-01-01   NaN
1  2000-01-02   NaN
2  2000-01-03   NaN
3  2000-01-06  33.7
4  2000-01-07  57.3
5  2000-01-08   NaN
6  2000-01-09   NaN 

Teva.csv
         Date    Low
0  2000-01-01  332.7
1  2000-01-02   59.3
2  2000-01-03  663.9
3  2000-01-06   43.2
4  2000-01-07  121.6
5  2000-01-08    NaN
6  2000-01-09    NaN
```

Query: 
 The above code does join/merge of Dates.txt and the required file **separately**. However, my requirement is to get a single csv file with Dates in Column0, 1st company in Col2, 2nd company in Col3 etc. Can someone please help? I am a complete noob to Python and I couldn't find any Q&A on this forum for this problem.

Using Python 3.8.0 on Windows.

**Update:**

---

As suggested by [FBruzzesi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12411536/fbruzzesi), by converting list of lists into simple list, I was able to achieve what I wanted:

```
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as List_txt:
    list_csv = csv.reader(List_txt);     #print(reader, '\n');
    flat_list = [val for sublist in list_csv for val in sublist];   #print(flat_list, '\n');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pandas and list comprehension you can do something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# List of csv to retrieve
list_csv = pd.read_csv('../List.csv').tolist()

# List of dates
dates = pd.read_csv('../Dates.txt').tolist()

#Load only the csv's in the list
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f'../{ticker}.csv', index_col='Date', usecols=['Date', 'Low']).rename(columns={'Low': ticker}) for ticker in list_csv], axis=1)

# Filter dates
df = df[df.index.isin(dates)]

# Write to a new csv
df.to_csv('../merged_file.csv')
```

Comment: The 1st & 2nd lines gave error that DataFrame object has no attribute 'tolist'. So I made it `pd.read_csv('List.csv').values.tolist();`
However, the 3rd line 
`df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f'D:/SO/dir/{ticker}.csv', index_col='Date', usecols=['Date', 'Low']).rename(columns={'Low': ticker}) for ticker in list_csv], axis=1)`
gives the following error:
_File b"D:/SO/dir/['Google'].csv" does not exist: b"D:/SO/dir/['Google'].csv"_

Comment: The fact that you see 'Google' within brackets make me think that you have a list of lists and not a list of tickers. Since I don't know the format of your data, you should manage to get in that format. For example you can load, access the column to get a pandas Series and then use .tolist() as I was thinking.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the help!